# Apache Zeppelin postgres Null Pointer Exception

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, sh, apache-zeppelin

I try to connect a query a remote postgres database -

```
%psql.sql

select * from my_schema.my_table limit 5
```

I have updated the interpreter values but I still get the following error -

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.postgresql.PostgreSqlInterpreter.executeSql(PostgreSqlInterpreter.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.postgresql.PostgreSqlInterpreter.interpret(PostgreSqlInterpreter.java:288)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.interpret(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:302)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:171)  at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I tried accessing from shell but got an error -

> Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2)

I suspect that it relates to the fact that it tries to get a password. However the same command + the password works on my terminal.

The other related issue is that the properties in the interpreter does not contain database name. I add it as `postgresql.database` but I am not sure if this property is used.

Please let me know if you have any idea how to solve it, Thanks!

Comment: Does the below answer helps? If not kindly add details as comments

Comment: It was helpful and therefor I upvoted it

Comment: did you find a way to solve this problem OP?

Answer (score 4):

Your property `postgresql.database` will not be picked by zeppelin.

Specify database name in postgres jdbc URL property. Like **jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database**

Refer, https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html for more detail on postgres jdbc URL

Comment: Thanks, this also resolves a Flyway 4.2.0 clean and migrate java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Some of your credentials might be wrong. I had the username typed incorrectly and got something similar:

`java.lang.NullPointerException at 
org.apache.zeppelin.postgresql.PostgreSqlInterpreter.executeSql(PostgreSqlInterpreter.java:202)`